# Focus in a QFileDialog::getExistingDirectory

Tags: qt, qt4

I am opening a directory using `QFileDialog::getExistingDirectory`. This is working fine, but there is something that is annoying me. If the parent directory of the directory I open has a lot of entries, the 'focus' is all the way at the bottom of the dialog. Like this:

[image: Actual behaviour]

The directory I specify (in this case c8) is the result from the previous time the dialog was used, and it is likely the user now wants either the next one down or a child. Either way, it requires a scrolling down action which I would like to avoid. Is it possible to open the dialog like so (in this case I use a2):

[image: Desired behaviour]

Comment: You may write your own dialog. That will not use native API and do exactly what you want. It is a bad practice to change behavior of native dialogs.

Comment: Try if `QFileDialog::selectFile()` with the name of the first file from that dir solves this. It may also help to dig into the code to see how this handled internally, perhaps you can derive a custom class and reimplement that part.